# List, add, edit, delete Windows Scheduled Tasks from the command-line

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, scheduled-task

Is there a command-line tool that can be used to programatically list, add, edit and delete Windows Scheduled tasks?

I realize that there are better alternatives to Scheduled Tasks, but I need to make changes to an existing set of tasks on a large number of PCs and would like to script it.

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [This link at Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738335(WS.10).aspx) on using [at](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755618(WS.10).aspx) and [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785(WS.10).aspx) to manage scheduled tasks from the command line.

Comment: [at](https://ss64.com/nt/at.html) vs [schtasks](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html): https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/09/22/how-can-i-manage-scheduled-tasks-using-scripts/

Comment: Quote: **Schtasks replaces At.exe**, a tool included in previous versions of Windows. Although At.exe is still included in the Windows Server 2003 family, schtasks is the recommended command-line task scheduling tool. Link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks

Answer (score 3):

```
schtasks.exe /change /TN pepe /ENABLE
```